# Angular2 resolver for main (bootstrapped) component?

Tags: angular, resolve

Is it possible to resolve a service before main component in angular2?

Answer (score 0):

In the main route file, at the very top level, you can mention a resolver name which will be resolved just before the very top component loads (which is the bootstrapped component)

```
    {
    path: '',
    resolve: AppComponentResolve,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'somePath',
            component: SomeCOmponent
        }]
    }
```

And add the resolver as an injectable to the appComponent file

```
    @Injectable()
    export class AppComponentResolve implements Resolve<any> {

    resolve(){
      //return resolved data
     }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Execute the service in the resolve under app's default

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path:'', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home'},
  { 
    path: 'home',
    component: AppComponent,
    resolve: function(){
         //your service call 
    },
  { 
    path: 'path1/:id',
    component: YourComponent,
    resolve: {
      someObject: ComponentResolve
    }
  }
];

@Injectable()
export class ComponentResolve implements Resolve<Interface> {

  constructor(private yourService: YourService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return this.yourService.getMethod(route.params['id']);
  }
```

Comment: there is no route for my bootstrapped main component, `path: ''` redirects to `path: 'home', component: 'HomeComponent'`, the AppComponent is bootstrapped by `@NgModule({.....bootstrap:[AppComponent]`})`

Comment: I got a main.ts using `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);`

Comment: `{path:'', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home'},{path: 'home', component: HomeComponent}` nothing above these are the main routes

Comment: you can see my answer having a **resolve** property?

Comment: yeah for sure I see, maybe I am misunderstanding something but the AppComponent is not connected to the "empty path" route in my app. Instead it is bootstrapped by the main module. I do not want to use a resolve on the HomeComponent and `{path:'', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home', resolve:{...}},{path: 'home', component: HomeComponent}` is not working

Comment: @MaxSolid check my updated answer. my bad I modified

Comment: Nope this is still not what I tried.. AppComponent is the "root" component of my app (without a route) doing stuff like header and navigation in the template, while HomeComponent with the `path: 'Home'` route is the component used to generate the homepage displayed in the `<router-outlet>` of the AppComponent's template. So I do not need a resolve on the HomeComponent instead I need it on the "routeless" main AppComponent of my app.

Comment: Lets continue in the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137712/discussion-between-aravind-and-max-solid)

Comment: This solution just names the component at the 'home' route `AppComponent`, that dose not make it the bootstrapped component.